# PHP work with functions

Tags: php, forms, function

i have a form on my website, I want to print in header in footer text when someone fill this form.
Example header:
Hello Name surname

Example footer:
Date Name Surname

Here is how i did this

This is my form

```
        <form name="forma1" class="form1" method="post" action="forma_vjezba.php">


        <p>Vaše ime : </p>
        <input name="name" type="text" />
        <br /><br />


        <p>Vaše prezime : </p>
        <input name="surname" type="text" />
        <br /><br />


        <p>Datum rođenja :</p>
        <input name="date" type="date" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <p>Vaša Poruka :</p>
        <textarea name="message" type="text"></textarea>

        <br /> <br />

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />

    </form>
```

and php code

```
<div id="header">

    <h1><?php
        if ( ! $_POST["submit"] ){
        echo  "Pozdrav stranče neznam ništa o tebi."  . $_POST["name"] ;
        ?> </h1>
     <?php }
        else {
        echo "Pozdrav " . $_POST["name"] ." ". $_POST["surname"]; }
     ?>


</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p><?php
        if ( ! $_POST["submit"] ){
        echo  "Napisao bih sada (c) ali neznam tko si." ;
        ?> 
     <?php }
        else {
        echo "(c) " . $_POST["date"] ." ". $_POST["name"] ." ". $_POST["surname"]; }
     ?></p>
</div>
```

So this works but I want to use a function, I must use function. Header and footer must have a function, she returns me a clean value then I print what she returns me.
Every functions call on the begining and function check_post and variavble name, and then she returns 1 or 0 depends what is in POST variable.

```
function header_print ($name, $surname){
```

}

I am a beginner in php so this is where i stuck, on functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want us to give you a tutorial on how functions work? Have you tried reading the manual, a book or any of the myriad of tutorials Google will spit out?

Comment: Print out form with functions, in header in footer, just one example how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (edited)

**HTML**

```
<?php require 'functions.php'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My site</title>
        ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <?php echo header_print('John', 'Doolittle'); ?>
        </header>
        .... <!-- your page content -->
        <footer>
            <?php echo footer_print('John', 'Doolittle'); ?>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP** (functions.php)

```
function header_print($first_name, $last_name) {
    return 'Hi '. $first_name .' '. $last_name .'. How are you doing?';
}

function footer_print($first_name) {
    return 'Hi '. $first_name .'. Thanks for reading my whole website!';
}
```

Comment: I must use return and later call a function

Comment: Well, like this then?

Comment: It's ok now, but I can't understand, how to solve like that: Every function, call on the begining check_post function i variable (variable $name) and then return 1 or 0 depends of content in POST variable

Comment: `function($a, $b) { return $a == $b; }`... But please try to ask a new question, in where you try to make your problem sound and clear... I really don't know what you're trying to achieve....